# Is there a way update Quicksight email reports to today's date?

Tags: parameters, report, updates, amazon-quicksight

I want to send a daily dashboard summary to all the users, but Quicksight doesnt't update the emailed report to today's date. It's always stuck on the parameter static default date. Is there a way to dynamically update the static default date?

I have a dynamic date set to today so the dashboard always loads on today's date, but the report keeps being generated on the same day every day. Also, Quicksight doesn't let the date parameter be created without a static default date (even though I have a dynamic one)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong in your syntax, when the default static date is not overwritten by a dynamic date; can ne as simply as having todays_date vs. today_date or case sensitivity.